# Where are Android Wear Proguard output files

Tags: android, proguard, wear-os

I have Proguard enabled on both the wear app and mobile app, using gradle in Android Studio (0.8.2).  I know proguard is enabled as I have placed Thread.dumpStack() in both apps, and obscured code comes out.  I have found the mobile proguard output files including mappings.txt, and checked in there for my mobile method classes etc. All fine so far.  But then,

Where are the wear app proguard output files?  I have checked in mappings.txt for any wear related methods, but find none. Also check in all other folders of my project.

I am using the wearApp gradle rule for building.

The wear gradle includes:

```
productFlavors {
    freeapp {
        applicationId "com.barkside.app"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
             'proguard-project.txt'
    }
}
```

The mobile gradle includes:

```
dependencies {
    wearApp project(path: ':wear', configuration: 'freeappRelease')
```

Comment: Did you find the answer?